Move a row in Google sheet based on today's date
I am trying to make a spreadsheet to help my grandparents keep track of their doctor's appointments. They would like to have one sheet where they can write all of their upcoming appointments (one appointment per row), then have the row move to another sheet after the appointment has passed.
I was able to find this previous thread in which someone had the same goal. The user Pierre-Marie Richard posted the following code as a solution:
function approveRequests() {

  // Initialising
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var scheduleSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Flight Schedule");
  var pastSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Past Flight");
  var lastColumn = scheduleSheet.getLastColumn();

  // Check all values from your "Flight Schedule" sheet
  for(var i = scheduleSheet.getLastRow(); i > 0; i--){

    // Check if the value is a valid date
    var dateCell = scheduleSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
      var today = new Date();
      var test = new Date(dateCell);

      // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
      if(test < today){

        var rangeToMove = scheduleSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, scheduleSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        pastSheet.getRange(pastSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, scheduleSheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(rangeToMove);
        scheduleSheet.deleteRow(i);

      }
    }
  }
}

// Check is a valid date
function isValidDate(value) {
  var dateWrapper = new Date(value);
  return !isNaN(dateWrapper.getDate());

This solution does move rows from Sheet1 ("Flight Schedule) to Sheet2 ("Past Flight"). However, it seems to be moving rows based on whether or not there is a cell with a time value in a particular row. It will move the row if there is a time value, it will not move the row if there is not a time value (regardless of any date inputs).
I'm really not sure why it would do this. It seems like the problem would lie with var today = new Date();, but that doesn't make sense to me?
I'm sure the solution is something very simple, but I'm a mega beginner to coding. I would really like to help my grandparents with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Can you share your sample dummy data to understand how it looks like.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you considered the somewhat simpler solution with conditional formatting to gray out rows of past dates? The custom formula rule would look something like =$D2 < today().

You may even explore creating a friendly user webapp for your grandparents, where you could have navigation tabs: basic data entry form, view Upcomning Events, view past events. Google Sheet would serve as your database

It would probably be simplest to run the archival every time the spreadsheet is opened. If it is kept constantly open, you can add a menu item to let the user easily run the code, like this:
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user opens the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onOpen() event object.
*/
function onOpen(e) {
  moveRowsWhereDateIsInThePast();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Archive')
    .addItem('Move past appointments to archive', 'moveRowsWhereDateIsInThePast')
    .addToUi();
}


/**
* Moves rows where a date in a column is in the past to another sheet.
*/
function moveRowsWhereDateIsInThePast() {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 23 May 2024
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78521240/13045193
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dateRange = ss.getRange('Appointments!D1:D');
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Past appointments');
  const sourceSheet = dateRange.getSheet();
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const dateString_ = (date) => Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  const todayString = dateString_(new Date());
  const dateStrings = dataRange.getValues().flat()
    .map(date => date.getTime ? dateString_(date) : null);
  const data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let numRowsMoved = 0;
  for (let rowIndex = dateStrings.length - 1; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--) {
    if (!dateStrings[rowIndex] || dateStrings[rowIndex] >= todayString) {
      continue;
    }
    targetSheet.appendRow(data[rowIndex]);
    sourceSheet.deleteRows(rowIndex + 1, 1);
    numRowsMoved += 1;
  }
  if (numRowsMoved) {
    const message = `Moved ${numRowsMoved} rows from '${sourceSheet.getName()}' to '${targetSheet.getName()}'.`;
    console.log(message);
    ss.toast(message);
  }
}

See simple triggers and Utilities.formatDate().
